# Chip with price and functionality to the RDA1846?

Tags: baofeng, electronics

Is it possible to buy a cheap transceiver chip with similar functionality to the RDA1846?

I'm looking for something else, because I'm wary of buying a probably counterfeit chip on AliExpress, and I got a message after I ordered RDA1846 on that site from another seller:

> Dear friend, you take a picture of RDA1846S this product has been discontinued. Trouble you cancel the order

Comment: Why not buy the RDA1846?

Answer (score 1):

There is a REALLY cheap chip that has all the functionality of the rda1846, and is in fact is 100% compatible, with the same pinout and power requirements.

It is ... the rda1846: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/single-chip-transceiver-for-Walkie-Talkie-RDA1846-new-and-original/715898_694516758.html

You say you want a 'cheap' chip, well this one is pretty cheap!

Comment: Well, thank you for your effort for answering my question, but I'm looking for something else, because I'm wary to buy probably counterfeit chip on AliExpress, and getting messages after I've ordered RDA1846 on that site from another seller: Dear friend, you take a picture of RDA1846S this product has been discontinued. Trouble you cancel the order

Comment: If you look, there are other places selling them too

Comment: @DusanSukovic Thank you for explaining further. I've added that information to your question.